# Executing command in Plink from a batch file

Tags: ssh, putty, plink

I want to automate the export process which I take using `expdp` command in Oracle.

Following is the contents of batch file I have created to open PuTTY.

> @echo off
>
> "C:\Program Files\PuTTY\plink.exe" username@Ip_Addr -pw password -m Open_Putty.txt`

Following is the contents of `Open_Putty.txt` to execute different commands.

> echo $ORACLE_SID;
>
> Read oraenv;

But after opening `Open_Putty.bat` it disappears without showing any output.
Please help me with this. I want to set `oraenv` and run some more commands to take the backup.

Answer (score 4):

It's unlikely that `plink.exe` disappears without showing any output. I assume you execute the batch file from a Windows Explorer or other GUI application, so the Plink console window disappears once Plink finishes (possibly with error) and you cannot read the output (error).

Make sure you execute `plink.exe` from a console window (typically a `cmd.exe`) or add `pause` command to the end of the batch.

---

Make sure Plink can find the script file (`Open_Putty.txt`). As you do not specify a path to the file, it has to be located in your current working directory. Safer is to use a full path to the script file:

```
"C:\Program Files\PuTTY\plink.exe" username@Ip_Addr -pw password -m "C:\path\Open_Putty.txt"
```

---

The backtick symbol at the end of the command should probably not be there.

---

The name "Open PuTTY" is bit confusing. You are not using PuTTY at all. And even if you refer to Plink by "PuTTY", your script file (`Open_Putty.txt`) is not opening PuTTY nor Plink. It's executing remote commands. So you should better name it `export.txt` or similar.