# Best way to script remote SSH commands in Batch (Windows)

Tags: linux, windows, batch-file, ssh, putty

I am looking to script something in batch which will need to run remote ssh commands on Linux. I would want the output returned so I can either display it on the screen or log it.

I tried `putty.exe -ssh user@host -pw password -m command_run` but it doesn't return anything on my screen.

Anyone done this before?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The `-m` switch of PuTTY takes a *path to a script file* as an argument, not a *command*.

Reference: https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-cmdline-m

So you have to save your command (`command_run`) to a plain text file (e.g. `c:\path\command.txt`) and pass that to PuTTY:

```
putty.exe -ssh user@host -pw password -m c:\path\command.txt
```

---

Though note that you should use Plink (a command-line connection tool from PuTTY suite). It's a console application, so you can redirect its output to a file (what you cannot do with PuTTY).

A command-line syntax is identical, an output redirection added:

```
plink.exe -ssh user@host -pw password -m c:\path\command.txt > output.txt
```

See [Using the command-line connection tool Plink](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter7.html).

And with Plink, you can actually provide the command directly on its command-line:

```
plink.exe -ssh user@host -pw password command > output.txt
```

---

Similar questions:
[Automating running command on Linux from Windows using PuTTY](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6147203/850848)
[Executing command in Plink from a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28134912/850848)

Comment: Thanks. I ended up writing most stuff in batch and then only do commands I need to using plink.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use `Bash on Ubuntu on Windows` directly. E.g.,

```
bash -c "ssh -t user@computer 'cd /; sudo my-command'"
```

Per Martin Prikryl's comment below:

> The -t enables terminal emulation. Whether you need the terminal emulation for sudo depends on configuration (and by default you do no need it, while many distributions override the default). On the contrary, many other commands need terminal emulation.

Comment: The `-t` enables terminal emulation. Whether you need the terminal emulation for `sudo` depends on configuration (and by default you do no need it, while many distributions override the default). On the contrary, many other commands need terminal emulation. So your last paragraph is pretty much incorrect. +1 anyway.

Comment: Cool thanks. I was just thinking this morning I should have `ssh --help` before mentioning what I did about `-t`! Updated answer with your information.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative option you could install OpenSSH http://www.mls-software.com/opensshd.html and then simply `ssh user@host -pw password -m command_run`

Edit: After a response from [user2687375](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2687375/user2687375) when installing, select client only. Once this is done you should be able to initiate SSH from command.

Then you can create an ssh batch script such as

```
ECHO OFF
CLS
:MENU
ECHO.
ECHO ........................
ECHO SSH servers
ECHO ........................
ECHO.
ECHO 1 - Web Server 1
ECHO 2 - Web Server 2
ECHO E - EXIT
ECHO.

SET /P M=Type 1 - 2 then press ENTER:
IF %M%==1 GOTO WEB1
IF %M%==2 GOTO WEB2
IF %M%==E GOTO EOF

REM ------------------------------
REM SSH Server details
REM ------------------------------

:WEB1
CLS
call ssh user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
cmd /k

:WEB2
CLS
call ssh user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
cmd /k
```

Comment: because You are suggesting ssh server, and OP want a way to execute remote command from bat script. Also, after installing program ou suggested, my antivir went crazy.

Comment: Awesome how would I do password?

Comment: I'd use `-ssh user@host -pw password -m c:\path\command.txt` as suggested above