# PuTTY/KiTTY alternative on Windows command line

Tags: shell, server, connection, command-line-interface, putty

I want to connect to a Windows Server without the need of using [KiTTY](http://kitty.9bis.net/) or [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/). Is there a easy way connecting to a server? I want to do some command-line operations and I wondered, if there is fast way to execute operations from Windows command line.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only latest versions of Windows 10 come with built-in SSH client. It's [Win32-OpenSSH](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH) version of OpenSSH `ssh`.

On older Windows versions, you can manually extract [Win32-OpenSSH package](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/releases) (do not install the server, just extract the archive and use the included `ssh.exe` binary).

---

Another option on Windows 10 x64 is to install [Windows subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about). The OpenSSH `ssh` is included.

---

Or use a 3rd party SSH client.

PuTTY is by far the most widely used SSH client for Windows. And easy to install and use.

---

If you want to automate commands, use [Plink](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter7.html). It's a console SSH client. Plink is part of the PuTTY package.

See [Best way to script remote SSH commands in Batch (Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28197540/850848)

Answer (score 1):

IVT Secure Access: http://www.ivtssh.nl/

Below are some of the elegant ways/capabilities of this terminal.

1. **Single sign-on:**
   Support for GSSAPI allows password-less login using SSH or Telnet with your Windows credentials. It has many ways to login without the need for typing passwords.
2. **Quick search like “Spotlight”**: Just press 1-2 characters of the server name to quickly select the server to connect. It is far better than the tedious job of going through the saved list of saved sessions manually.
3. **Automatically highlight warning and error messages on screen**.
   Red for "error, failed", yellow for "warnings" and green for "success, passed". This is great when running something that produces a lot of output on the screen. The colored text is very difficult to miss. More keywords can also be added to have them highlighted by default.
4. **Automatically logs all sessions to a file name that is displayed on the screen**. The list can be accessed with a keyboard short cut and each listing can be clicked to open the corresponding file in default editor.
   This eliminates the need to open the file and search for different warnings and errors manually after a big verbose script that also logs.
5. **Mouse Support.**
   Any filename on screen listed with an error message can be directly clicked with mouse to open it in default editor.  IVT can even generate VI commands to allow positioning of the cursor with the mouse within this popular Unix editor. The user can program a combination of keyboard and mouse keys to trigger a user-defined script.
6. **Built-in WinSCP support**, drag & drop file transfer
   The terminal has built-in WinSCP support and function like "start WinSCP to this host, send the file to this server, send the file to windows host", that does not require any extra logging step.
   Alternatively, drop a file on the terminal window and it will be transferred to the host.
7. **Tabbed window support**
   The terminal supports the tabs in a single window and easy navigation keys “CTRL + arrows”.
8. **Each tab has a progress indicator.**
   The terminal has a progress indicator on each tab for the session they represent.
   A grey moving clock for showing terminal is still running the last command. A green "checked" box for command completed. This eliminates the need to go to different sessions to check the completion of a long-running command.
9. **VT220 compatibility**: IVT scores 110 out of 110 on the vttest compatibility test. The highest rating found for PuTTY is 82, which means various older programs that require exact emulation will work with IVT and fail with PuTTY.
10. **Supports traditional search**
    It also supports "CTRL-F" with which you can search for something on-screen and history buffer in upwards/downwards direction.
11. Run command simultaneously on every logged-in session.  If you have to run something on every "logged-in session", like an update, build, etc., the terminal has a capability to run the same command on every logged-in terminal and after it is started, the progress indicators on each tab will show the status of that command on every machine.
12. **Color schemes**
    The terminal has many color-schemes built-in that fulfill the coloring need for everyone.
13. **Launch Duplicate session with keyboard shortcuts.**
    The launched session is the exact duplicate of the session it duplicates (same host, user, and working directory).
14. **Map actions/scripts to keyboard keys**: The default setting of the terminal is good enough for everybody but it can be customized to use each and every keyboard shortcut to run scripts/tasks and that means that doing some specific things on different servers is just a keyboard key press away.
15. **X-Server**: The terminal can be easily integrated with X-server.
16. **Configurable**: It has literally hundreds of configurable options, which allow IVT to be customized to fit any given situation or environment. Scripts can dynamically change all settings to configure sessions automatically.