# Running a command in SSH from command prompt

Tags: unix, ssh, command-prompt, telnet, gemini

I am trying to access unix from command prompt using SSH connection with the below command

C:\Program Files\PuTTY>putty.exe -ssh gemini -l usename -pw password

Now i also want to run command in gemini from command prompt. 
Will that be possible ?

I have found few solutions as below

C:\Program Files\PuTTY>putty.exe -ssh gemini -l username -pw password -m "C:\path\cmd.txt"

But running that just opens my putty and closes and not sure what is missing.

can someone help me with this please ?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28197540/best-way-to-script-remote-ssh-commands-in-batch-windows

Comment: it says access denied.
1. plink.exe -ssh gemini -l username  -pw password  -m "C:\path\cmd.txt" >  output.txt
2. plink.exe -ssh gemini -l patlolls -pw putty666 -m "C:\path\cmd.txt" >  output.txt.
i have tried above two commands. Not sure access to what is denied.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to remove doble quotes in file path?

Comment: Yes i did and it is the same.